# LINQ: With Many to many relationship, select from list

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework

I've having trouble figuring out how to select based on a list in a many to many relationship.

I've created with entities-framework the following entities and many to many relationship (please correct me if I'm going about this wrong) :

```
public class Foo {
  public int FooID { get; set; }
  public string FooName { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<FooBar> Foo_Bar { get; set; }
}

public class Bar {
  public int BarID { get; set; }
  public string BarName { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<FooBar> Foo_Bar { get; set; }
}

public class FooBar {
  public int FooBarID{ get; set; }
  public virtual int BarID { get; set; }
  public virtual int FooID { get; set; }
}
```

In my code my controller will receive a list of Foo and I need to find all the Bar with those foo ( both with only and with any )

I'm at a loss for where to start really... this is all I've come up with:

```
public PartialViewResult SearchAnyBar(List<Foo> foos) {
    List<FooBar> foobars = _db.FooBar.Select(fb => fb).ToList<FooBar>();
    List<Bar> searchedBars = new List<Bar>();

    foreach (Foo f in foos)
    {
        foreach (FooBar fXb in foobars) 
        {
            if (fXb.FooID == f.FooID)
            {
                searchedBars.Add(_db.Bar.Where(b => b.BarID == fXb.BarID).FirstOrDefault());
            }
        }
    }        

    return PartialView("The View", searchBars);
}
```

This works for the grabbing any Bar however:

1. I'm pretty positive there's a much better way of doing this, is there a way to select based on a list instead of going about 2 foreach loop?
2. I'm not sure how to go about getting a list of Foos where the Foo has ALL the Bars and not just ANY.

Comment: Do you have other properties in FooBar class ? If no, you don't need that Entity...

Comment: I don't... I created that class to create the m2m relationship. Is this wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove FooBar class.

Just create a `public virtual ICollection<Foo> Foos {get;set;}` in you Bar class

and a `public virtual ICollection<Bar> Bars {get;set;}` in your Foo Class

This will create a many to many relationship (with a relation table named [Foo-Bar] or something like that in your db... but who minds, you will be using objects).

then

any query :

```
var listOfFooId = <a list of Foo>.Select(m => m.FooId).ToList;
return _db.Bar.Where(m => m.Foos.Any(x => listOfFooId.Contains(x.FooId)));
```

not sure I understood well the "only" and "any", but if you have problems with the other query... ask.

Comment: Wow thanks... okay. 1. I had an inkling that my extra class was useless. This confirms it. I've changed it and recreated tables and it works great. 2. the LINQ statement works great aswell. I'm still trying to wrap my head around it but it works. 3. The last part i'm trying to figure out is this. a) the current statement returns any bar where there is any of the foos in the list. But now I want to return ONLY the bar where there are ALL the foos in the list. Does that make sense?

Comment: Nevermind... a quick playing around and replacing Any in the statement with All does the trick. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but it looks like you just need a join here... Joining on all the Bars off of all the FooBars joined to the Foos passed in, right?

```
public PartialViewResult SearchAnyBar(List<Foo> foos) { 

    var bars = (from f in foos
               join fb in _db.FooBars on f.Id equals fb.FooId
               join b in _db.Bars on fb.BarId equals b.BarId
               select b).ToList();



        return PartialView("The View", bars); 
    }
```